# Change order of combined product tabs

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, tabs

I found and implemented the following code. I need the Additional Information to display BEFORE the Product Description content. I have been looking through posts for hours with no luck.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', function( $tabs ) {
unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );
return $tabs;
}, 98 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', function( $tabs ) {
$tabs['description']['callback'] = function() {
    global $product;
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
    if ( $product && ( $product->has_attributes() || apply_filters(
'wc_product_enable_dimensions_display', $product->has_weight() || $product->has_dimensions() ) ) ) 
        wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/additional-information.php' );
    }
};
return $tabs;
}, 98 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally just swap the order of them in the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', function( $tabs ) {
$tabs['description']['callback'] = function() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product && ( $product->has_attributes() || apply_filters(
'wc_product_enable_dimensions_display', $product->has_weight() || $product->has_dimensions() ) ) ) 
        wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/additional-information.php' );
    }
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
};
return $tabs;
}, 98 );
```